# Where can I add exception handling in a Java class definition?

Tags: java

So, I had to create two files. One is a class definition. The other one uses the class' methods/fields.

**(Artifact.java) Artifact Class definition:**

```
    public class Artifact {

    int artNumber;
    String arcName;
    String artType;
    int artYear;
    double artWeight;

    Artifact(int artNumber, String arcName, String artType, int artYear,double artWeight) {
        this.artNumber = artNumber;
        this.arcName = arcName;
        this.artType = artType;
        this.artYear = artYear;
        this.artWeight = artWeight;
    }

    public void changeArtYear(int x) {
        this.artYear = x;
    }

    public void changeArcName(String x) {
        this.arcName = x;
    }

    public int getArtNumber() {
        return artNumber;
    }

    public String getArcName() {
        return arcName;
    }

    public String getArtType() {
        return artType;
    }

    public int getArtYear() {
        return artYear;
    }

    public double getArtWeight() {
        return artWeight;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return("The artifact #"+artNumber+" was discovered by "+arcName+". The artifact is made of "+artType+" and was discovered in "+artYear+". The artifact weighs "+artWeight+" kilograms.");
    }


}
```

**(ArtifactTester.java) Testing methods:**

```
public class ArtifactTester {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Artifact test = new Artifact(88888888,"ben","clay",1624,46.4);          

    System.out.println(test.toString()); //toString()
    System.out.println(test.getArtWeight()); //getArtWeight()
    System.out.println(test.getArtYear()); //getArtYear()
    System.out.println(test.getArtType()); //getArtType()   
    System.out.println(test.getArcName()); //getArcName()   
    System.out.println(test.getArtNumber()); //getArtNumber()   
    test.changeArcName("zack");
    test.changeArtYear(1400);
        System.out.println(test.getArcName()); //getArcName()   
        System.out.println(test.getArtYear()); //getArtYear()
}
}
```

Anyways, my teacher to told me to add exception handling, but I am not sure where I would add exception handling.

**Question:** Is it possible to use exception handling in this situation?

Comment: Go back to your teacher for clarification

Comment: It seem your teacher has not provided full information , can you please ask them in detail? Do they need only simple `try/catch` handling or need other specific condition handling also.

Comment: Well `artNum` needs to be 8 digits long, not sure if knowing that changes anything.

Comment: @RobertTossly so wait, do you mean that you want to throw an exception if artNum isn't 8 digits then handle this Exception? Because thats also do-able, just a bit different than my answer.

Comment: Yes^ it should throw an exception

Comment: @RobertTossly ok, listen: I got to go to school right now :(. Sorry, but I will try to edit my answer so it incorporates this as soon as I get home and finish up my HW. In the meantime, try googling "create your own exception java", or read through that tutorialspoint article I linked. It's sort of a more advanced topic when you haven't properly learned about Exceptions yet but you can give it a shot. I would like to remind you however, that in this case you could just use an if() statement to check that its 8 characters. But, if your teacher wants an exception then you will have to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to be blunt. **Yes. Of course.** You can use exception handling wherever and whenever you please (most of the time). Although, in this specific case I don't really see a good reason for it. But, I'll take your word for the need.
Now, as for where to handle exceptions, this is up to you. You can add exception handling in one of two places. You can either add exception handling when you call the methods like this:

```
try { //try executing a block of code which may throw exception
    test.toString()
}

catch(Exception e) { //use Exception for all types of exceptions, or make it specific 
    //do something here if the exception is thrown
}
```

or you can excpetion handle in the methods themselves like so:

```
 public void changeArtYear(int x) {
    try{
        this.artYear = x;
    }

    catch(Exception e){ //catch the exception that could be thrown
         //do something
    }
}
```

This should do the trick in your case if you want to add exception handling here. However, I would strongly urge you to learn exception handling and the different exceptions in Java, it is one of the most improtant fundamentals to programming in this language.

Also, let me point this out again: In this program, there is really no need to use exception handling except for practice. There is nothing here that would throw an exception for any reason. (Except maybe a `NullPointerException` if you passed a null parameter through one of your method calls)

**Good Reference/Tutorial:**
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

This site is an excellent java reference point in general, but specifically for your question today, this page shows you how to work with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use exception handling in this situation?

I don't think so. You should probably go and ask your teacher.

In your code, `Artifact` is just a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). It would not throw any exceptions. All you do in the class is getters and setters, right? How can that throw any exceptions?

You can throw exceptions though. In your setters, you can check whether the argument is `null` before setting it to the fields. For example:

```
public void changeArcName(String x) {
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentException ("x is null!");
    this.arcName = x;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use brute force and use `try...catch`. like this:

```
Artifact test = new Artifact(88888888,"ben","clay",1624,46.4);          

    try {
        System.out.println(test.toString()); //toString()
        System.out.println(test.getArtWeight()); //getArtWeight()
        System.out.println(test.getArtYear()); //getArtYear()
        System.out.println(test.getArtType()); //getArtType()   
        System.out.println(test.getArcName()); //getArcName()   
        System.out.println(test.getArtNumber()); //getArtNumber()   
        test.changeArcName("zack");
        test.changeArtYear(1400);
        System.out.println(test.getArcName()); //getArcName()   
        System.out.println(test.getArtYear()); //getArtYear()
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace ();
    }
```

Warning: The catch block can never be reached!

I don't know whether the above is what your teacher wants. Just try both methods and hand it in and see what he/she says!

Comment: Yeah, I'm really confused to about why the teacher is making them handle exceptions that will never be thrown... I guess there could be a NullPointer but you would have to intentionally set a null as a parameter. There must be something he hasn't told us about the assignment. Maybe he is supposed to try passing null as an argument?